# Load the local table with data from server

Tags: android, mysql, sql-update

I have an online database with which my android application contacts. All the details that the app needs, is stored in the online MySQL database. My problem here is, I have a sql query, `"SELECT sum(amount) FROM donations WHERE aid = '" + aid2 + "'"` which sums the appropriate data in a row and returns an integer value. In my class, I create the table like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase dbs = openOrCreateDatabase("dbname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

dbs.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS donations(create_time VARCHAR, id VARCHAR, intent VARCHAR, state VARCHAR, amount INT, currency_code VARCHAR, short_descritpion VARCHAR, aid INT);");
```

But when it's queried, it gives 0. I used "DB Browser for SQLite" to check the local database file of the app running on the emulator, and found that the table is empty. I manually added a couple of rows to the file and added it to the emulator again. This time I got the desired result because of the manually added rows.

My question is, how can I make the local db update with the online db when the class is loaded?

Comment: what u need here are webservices to query your database on server and respond with data to your device's request.

Comment: @Nitesh, any simple example for this?

Comment: Read about restful services and their integration with android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! I first created a PHP file that returns a JSON array to the app. From there, I read it and looped through the array while inserting the values to the SQLite database :)